# Rails: Obfuscating Image URLs on Amazon S3? (security concern)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, amazon-s3

To make a long explanation short, suffice it to say that my Rails app allows users to upload images to the app that they will want to keep *in* the app (meaning, no hotlinking).

So I'm trying to come up with a way to obfuscate the image URLs so that the address of the image depends on whether or not that user is logged in to the site, so if anyone tried hotlinking to the image, they would get a 401 access denied error.

I was thinking that if I could route the request through a controller, I could re-use a lot of the authorization I've already built into my app, but I'm stuck there.

What I'd like is for my images to be accessible through a URL to one of my controllers, like:

```
http://railsapp.com/images/obfuscated?member_id=1234&pic_id=7890
```

If the user where to right-click on the image displayed on the website and select "Copy Address", then past it in, it would be the SAME url (as in, wouldn't betray where the image is actually hosted).

The actual image would be living on a URL like this:

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/s3username/assets/member_id/pic_id.extension
```

Is this possible to accomplish? Perhaps using Rails' `render` method? Or something else? I know it's possible for PHP to return the correct headers to make the browser think it's an image, but I don't know how to do this in Rails...

UPDATE: I want all users of the app to be able to view the images if and ONLY if they are currently logged on to the site. If the user does not have a currently active session on the site, accessing the images directly should yield a generic image, or an error message.

Comment: (I would POST to be RESTful,..) in this case restful would be GET a url like obfuscated/:member_id/:pic_id since you are retrieving an object and not changing your application state...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 allows you to construct query strings for requests which allow a time-limited download of an otherwise private object.  You can generate the URL for the image uniquely for each user, with a short timeout to prevent reuse.

See [the documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/index.html?RESTAuthentication.html), look for the section "Query String Request Authentication Alternative".  I'd link directly, but the frame-busting javascript prevents it.

Comment: Thanks, but I understand that this could mean that if the url of the image was given to somebody not logged on to the system who tried to access it while the actual user was online and on their account, because the image hasn't timed out yet, they WOULD be able to see the image. In this regard, I don't think this would work for me. I'm curious to know what you think of the solution I came up with, though, as an alternative.

Comment: How would that hypothetical attacker get the URL?  If someone has enough access to pass it to them, they have enough access to copy-and-paste the image :).  Note that the URL changes each time you generate it; you could probably make the timeout as short as a minute (must be long enough for the containing page to load, needn't necessarily be any longer).

Answer (score 2):

Should the images be available to only that user or do you want to make it available to a group of users (friends)?

In any case if you want to stop hotlinking you should *not* store the image files under DocumentRoot of your webserver.

If the former, you could store the image on the server as MD5(image_file_name_as_exposed_to_user + logged_in_username_from_cookie). When the user requests image_file_name_as_exposed_to_user, in your rails app, construct the image filename as previously mentioned and then open the file in rails app and write it out (after first setting Content-Type in response header appropriately). This is secure by design.

If the image could be shared with friends, then you should not incorporate username in constructed filename but rest of the advice should work.

Answer (score 2):

This is late in the day to be answering, but another option altogether would be to store the files in MongoDB's GridFS, served through a bit of Rack Middleware that requires auth to be passed. Pretty much as secure as you like, and the URLs don't even need obfuscation.

The other benefit of this is in the availability of the files and the future scalability of the system.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your responses, but I'm still skeptical as to whether or not "timing out" the URL from Amazon is a very effective way to go.

I've updated my question above to be a little more clear about what I'm trying to do, and trying to prevent.

After some experimentation, I've come up with a way to do what I want to do in my Rails App, though this solution is not without downsides.  Effectively what I've done is to construct my `image_tag` with a URL that points to a controller, and takes a `path` parameter. That controller first tests whether or not the user is authorized to see the image, then it fetches the *content* of the image in a separate request, and stores the *content* in an instance variable, which is then passed to a `repond_to` view to return the image, successfully obfuscating the actual image's URL (since that request is made separately).

Cons:

1. Adds to request time (I feel that the additional time it takes to do this double-request is acceptable considering the privacy this method gives me)
2. Adds some clutter to views and routes (a small amount, maybe a bit more than I'd like)
3. If the user is authorized, and tries to access the image directly, the image is downloaded immediately rather than displayed in the browser (anyone know how to fix this? Modify HTTP headers? Only seems to do this with the `jpg`, though...)
4. You have to make a separate view for each file format you intend to serve (two for me, `jpg` and `png`)

Are there any other cons or considerations I should be aware of with this method? So far what I've listed, I can live with...

(Refactoring welcome.)

---

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def obfuscate_image
    respond_to do |format|
      if current_user
        format.jpg { @obfuscated_image = fetch_url "http://s3.amazonaws.com/#{Settings.bucket}/#{params[:path]}" }
      else
        format.png { @obfuscated_image = fetch_url "#{root_url}/images/assets/profile/placeholder.png" }
      end
    end
  end

  protected

  # helps us fetch an image, obfuscated
  def fetch_url(url)
    r = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
    if r.is_a? Net::HTTPSuccess
      r.body
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

**views/application/obfuscate_image.png.haml** & **views/application/obfuscate_image.jpg.haml**

```
= @obfuscated_image
```

**routes.rb**

```
map.obfuscate_image 'obfuscate_image', :controller => 'application', :action => 'obfuscate_image'
```

**config/environment.rb**

```
Mime::Type.register "image/png", :png
Mime::Type.register "image/jpg", :jpg
```

**Calling an obfuscated image**

```
= image_tag "/obfuscate_image?path=#{@user.profile_pic.path}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that as far as I know you need the images on S3 to be World-readable for them to be accessible. At some point in the process an HTTP GET is going to have to be performed to retrieve the image, which is going to expose the real URL to tools that can sniff HTTP, such as Firebug.

Incidentally, 37signals don't consider this to be a huge problem because if I view an image in my private Backpack account I can see the public S3 URL in the browser address bar. Your mileage may vary...

Comment: Have just seen Andrew's answer above. That's clearly the way to go.